# Element wise comparison in R

Tags: arrays, r, loops

I'm attempting to write a for loop that will compare values between two individuals, but not the same individual. The following data frame contains values for five subjects:

```
           Value1 
Subject1   0      
Subject2   1      
Subject3   5      
Subject4   6      
Subject5   8
```

I've written a double loop that creates a 'Value2' variable based on the following criteria:

1. If the subject has a larger Value1, then the result is +1.
2. If the subject has an equal Value1, then the result is 0.
3. If the subject has a smaller Value1, then the result is -1.

For example, Subject 1's Value1 is smaller than the other four subjects; this should result in -4. So far the loop I've written works for the first subject but fails to iterate to the second subject.

```
Value2<-0
i = 0
w = 0

for(i in 1:length(Value1)){
    for(j in 1:length(Value1)){
        if(i != j){
            Value1[i] = w
            if(w > Value1[j]){
                Value2[i] = Value2[i] + 1
            }    
            if(w < Value1[j]){
                Value2[i] = Value2[i] - 1
            } 
            if(w == Value1[j]){
                Value2[i] = Value2[i] + 0
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

If I'm understanding the problem correctly, this should give you what you want

```
x <- c(0, 1, 5, 6, 8)
colSums(outer(x, x, '<')) - colSums(outer(x, x, '>'))
# [1] -4 -2  0  2  4
```

Or

```
-colSums(sign(outer(x, x, '-')))
# [1] -4 -2  0  2  4
```

Edit: If your vector is large (or even if it isn't, really) **use d.b.'s `rank` method instead**. The `outer` function will create an NxN matrix where N is the length of `x`. For example, when `x` is `sample(1e5)` `outer` will attempt to create a matrix >30Gb in size! This means most people's laptops in 2019 don't even have enough memory for this method to work on large vectors. With this same `x`, the method using `rank` provided by d.b. returns the result almost instantly.

Benchmark for vector of size 1000

```
x <- sample(1000)
microbenchmark(
outer_diff = colSums(-sign(outer(x, x, '-'))),
outer_gtlt = colSums(outer(x, x, '<')) - colSums(outer(x, x, '>')),
rank = {r <- rank(x); 2*(r - mean(r))}
)
# Unit: microseconds
#        expr      min         lq       mean    median        uq        max neval cld
#  outer_diff 15930.26 16872.4175 20946.2980 18030.776 25346.677  38668.324   100   b
#  outer_gtlt 14168.21 15120.4165 28970.7731 16698.264 23857.651 352390.298   100   b
#        rank   111.18   141.5385   170.8885   177.026   188.513    282.257   100  a
```

Answer (score 6):

```
x = c(0, 1, 5, 6, 8)
r = rank(x)
ans = 2 * (r - mean(r))
ans
#[1] -4 -2  0  2  4
```

Answer (score 3):

@IceCreamToucan's benchmark considers cases with distinct values (sampling without replacement), but if we extend to repeated values (covered by criterion 2 in the OP), I figured tabulating first saves time.

```
library(data.table)
# from @d.b's answer and comments from d.b, ICT
fdb = function(x) { 
  r = frank(x)
  2 * (r - mean(r))
}

# from @chinsoon's comment and some algebra
fdb2 = function(x) { 
  r = frank(x)
  2 * r - length(x) - 1
}

# tabulation with data.table
ff = function(x){
  nx = length(x)
  xDT = setDT(list(x=x))
  resDT = xDT[, .N, keyby=x][, res := 2L*cumsum(N) - N - nx]
  resDT[xDT, x.res]
}
```

Sample data and results:

```
nv = 1e4 # number of values
n = 1e7  # length of vector
x = sample(nv, n, replace=TRUE)

system.time(res_fdb <- fdb(x))
#    user  system elapsed 
#    0.32    0.09    0.24 

system.time(res_fdb2 <- fdb2(x))
#    user  system elapsed 
#    0.25    0.13    0.27 

system.time(res_ff <- ff(x))
#    user  system elapsed 
#    0.58    0.24    0.50 

identical(res_ff, as.integer(res_fdb))  # TRUE
identical(res_ff, as.integer(res_fdb2)) # TRUE
```

Turns out `ff()` not as fast as direct use of `data.table::frank`, taking roughly twice as long because grouping by distinct values is done twice: once to count, and again in a lookup.

---

I guess the tabulation can also be done with base R's `table`.

```
ft = function(x){
  nx = length(x)
  N  = table(x)
  cN = cumsum(N)
  res = 2L*cN - N - nx
  as.vector(res[as.character(x)])
}

system.time(res_ft <- ft(x))
#    user  system elapsed 
#    7.58    0.34    7.93 

identical(res_ff, res_ft)
# [1] TRUE
```

Comment: I think if you use `frank` instead of `rank` with db's function in the comment above it may be faster than `ff`.

Comment: @d.b and IceCreamToucan sorry about the oversight re calling rank twice. Feel free to edit the answer with a different version of the function (or multiple variants if the differences are interesting) and timings from your own computer. Otherwise I will probably give it a go tomorrow.

Comment: and possibly `fdb2 = function(x) {r = frank(x); 2 * (r - (length(x)+1) / 2)}` for marginal speedup

Answer (score 0):

I populate your data frame with:

```
val <-data.frame(row.names = paste0('Subject', 1:5), Value1=c(0,1,5,6,8))
```

I generate all non-trivial pairwise comparisons with `combn`

```
ind <- combn(rownames(val), 2)
```

And index the data frame with the combinations, and use the `sign` function to populate a -1, 0, or 1 based on the respective equality.

```
sign(val[ind[1, ], 1] - val[ind[2, ], 1])
```

Which gives a constant string of -1, consistent with the ordered values provided in the example data, i.e. each subject has progressively higher value for "Value1"

```
> sign(val[ind[1, ], 1] - val[ind[2, ], 1])
 [1] -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1
```